# divided difference involving derivatives

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

$f(x)= (x+1)^4 $

points where function is measured/sampled are 0 and 1.
I thought when we have two conservative derivative on same point$\ x$ as $f'(x)$, in next column their divided difference becomes $f''(x)$

so ,in the image, why then we have $ \frac{1}{2}f''(0)$  instead of just $f''(0)$

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try to construct this term in the normal way. It is easy to show that

$$f[x,x+h,x+2h]=\frac{f(x+2h)-2f(x+h)+f(x)}{2h^2}.$$

If $f$ is twice differentiable at $x$, then this difference tends to $\frac{1}{2}f^{''}(x),$ whenever $h\to 0$.